# jQuery trouble with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I'm looking to run a web scraper with PhantomJS and jQuery over a page that navigates with Javascript events. I'm stuck at the very first part. I've gotten the pages to load and to interact with the DOM elements, but the expected results are not there.

The page loads and the jQuery source is injected which is good. But when I automate the click of the button to toggle the right side-bar list, you can see by the console output that my sequence of steps is correct as well as the button I'm attempting to click is correct but no proof of the event is being triggred. If I replicate this action in the console with a *jQuery('button.toggle.list').click();* I can watch the side-bar toggle so I know I'm after the correct action.

I'm under the impression that I'm taking the right steps, but we all know that computers are only as smart as the person who programs them :) And I'm also very new to PhantomJS and server-side JavaScript. This could be a major theoretical error in the approach that I'm taking and way that I'm calling my functions. So obviously I'm making a mistake somewhere, especially since I'm getting very 'buggy' results. Sometimes, I'll run the script and get different results. (Sometimes the button is blue/active sometimes it's not in the after.png screenshot).

This is plugin-able source code for anyone who feels nice enough to run this in their Phantom setup. Be sure to include the jquery.min.js file in the same folder as the this .js source.

For what it's worth, I installed Phantom 2.1.1 on a 14.04 Ubuntu Server VM from Phantom's website based from their build.html link.

## Code

```
var page = new WebPage(),
url = 'http://www.talkcondo.com/toronto/';

page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1200,
    height: 800
};

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, line, source) {
    console.log( 'console > ' + msg);
};

page.onAlert = function (msg) {
    console.log('alert! > ' + msg);
};

var property_links = [];
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status === 'success') {
        // jquery.min.js file must be in same local folder as this .js file
        page.injectJs('jquery.min.js');         
        page.render("before.png");
        console.log('before.png');  
        page.evaluate(function() {
            console.log('evaluating...');
            setTimeout(function(){              
                console.log("Number of buttons: " + $("button.toggle.list").length);
                // I have also tried $("button.toggle.list").first().click(); and .trigger('click');
                $("button.toggle.list").click();
                console.log('button clicked...');           
            },5000);

        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render("after.png");
            console.log('after.png');   
        },15000)


    }
});
```

## Output

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# rm *.png && phantomjs test.js
before.png
console > evaluating...
console > Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required
console > Number of buttons: 1
console > button clicked...
after.png
```

## EDIT

After reading a little more around the internet I found this was a common fix for people. It made my code more predictable in the fact that the button that was supposed to be clicked was being clicked, but the sidebar was still not being toggled.

```
page.evaluate(function(){
            console.log('1');
            var a = document.querySelector("button.toggle.list");
            console.log(a);
            var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            e.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
            console.log("Number of buttons: " + a.length);
            console.log('button clicked...');
        });
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Does clicking work or not?

Comment: The code is very buggy, sometimes the click will occur but the side-bar will not toggle even though the button that is clicked will have t he 'active' class from being clicked. Sometimes the click won't happen. I have to be doing something wrong. I just can't seem to figure out what. I included an edit as well for further information.